# Comparing two types of confidence intervals in R using Monte Carlo: trouble understanding what's going on

Tags: r, confidence-interval, monte-carlo

In a course I'm taking, my professor includes the following code in his slides.

> [image] [image] [image]

I'm trying to understand what this code does, but perhaps more importantly I'm also trying to understand the statistical ideas that are supposedly being illustrated here. I will try to explain roughly what I see the code doing, and then ask questions at the end.

**Proposed Explanation of Code**

In the first slide, I believe it's understood that `x` is a sample of length `n` drawn from either `runif` or `rexp`. The professor defines a function `tstarint` that takes the sample `x` and computes its mean $\mu^*$  and the standard error of $\mu^*$, which he calls `se`.

Then, he creates a matrix in which each row contains one bootstrap sample of length `n` from `x`, and he does this `M` times. The line `dev` creates a column vector of length `M` containing $\overline{X^*} - \mu^*$ for each of the `M` bootstrap samples. This is the mean of each bootstrap sample, minus the mean of the original sample `x`.

The line `tst`, as far as I know, takes `dev` and divides each entry by $\sqrt{s^{2*}/n}$, where $s^{2*}$ is the variance of each bootstrap sample. (I am kind of confused by the code here so I might be wrong about this part.)

Essentially what has been done is that via repeated random sampling of `x`, distributions of $\overline{X^*} - \mu^*$ and $\frac{\overline{X^*} - \mu^*}{\sqrt{s^{2*}/n}}$ have been created. I don't fully understand the last three lines of the first slide, but I think they involve creating the `M` confidence intervals for each approach.

The second slide involves running the function and counting how many of each type of confidence interval contains the true mean (which is $0.5$ in the case of sampling from `runif`).

**Questions:**

1. One of the main points of the code is that the $\overline{X^*} - \mu^*$ confidence intervals contain the true mean relatively infrequently, but they are reasonably narrow, while the $\frac{\overline{X^*} - \mu^*}{\sqrt{s^{2*}/n}}$ confidence intervals contain the true expected value, but they're unusably wide. Why is this? I have no intuition for what's going on here. Does it have something to do with the $\sqrt{s^{2*}/n}$ making the second set of confidence intervals wider?
2. Are the differences in the last three lines of the first slide (`c1, c2` and `c`) relevant to the differences in the performance of the confidence intervals? I don't fully understand the code so I'm not sure.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Turing is reported to have said that it is possible to write code so that no one can discover its purpose. Presumably, this was an incentive toward adequate commenting and documentation. Wise practices even for code one imagines to be transparent. Perhaps unintentionally, your professor has given you a nice lesson on the advantages of good commenting of code.